# Persisting Table data in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net

am populating a table dynamically, which includes a checkbox with an id  associated with it and then display it to the user. I do not have problems with the display part. 
After the user checks some specified checkboxes and hits the submit button, I would like to get his choices, Checkbox that is checked and its associated Id but during postback, my table neither has  any of the rows I added dynamically nor does it have of the user's selection. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Cheers
Ip Doh

My aspx page is as follows

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true"   runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="dummyLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="submitButton"  onclick="async_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

         <asp:Table ID="usrTable"  EnableViewState="true" runat="server">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Id"/>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Customer Name"/>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    </asp:Table>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

I have the following in the code file

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CreateTable();
        }
if (IsPostBack)
        {
            List<int> choices = GetUserChoices();

            //Do Something with user choices
        }



    }


protected List<int> GetUserChoices()
    {
        List<int> choices = new List<int>();
        foreach (TableRow row in usrTable.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = row.Controls[0] as CheckBox;

            if ((cb != null) && (cb.Checked))
            {
                choices.Add(int.Parse(cb.Text));
            }
        }

        return choices;
    }

    void CreateTable()
    {
        dummyLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();            
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.Text = i.ToString();
            cb.AutoPostBack = true;
            cb.EnableViewState = true;
            cell1.Controls.Add(cb);

            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            cell2.Text = String.Format("Clm : {0} - Row : {1}", 2, i);

            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.Cells.Add(cell1);
            row.Cells.Add(cell2);

            usrTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

The label value is persisted, whereas my table does not have any rows that i added.

Comment: Give us the code you used to generate the table. Any control not marked as runat="server" will not maintain viewstate and thus will not be present on the post back. The values will be avaliable using the Request.Form or Request.QueryString properties.

Comment: Your createTable method is not getting called on PostBack.

Comment: I basically want to know the checkboxes in the dynamic table that the user has checked. Looking through other posts, it seems i do not have a way to get the whole table back but instead recreate it, am ok with it but would like to find a way to get the user's selection

Answer (score 0):

doh, i forgot to set the id for the CheckBox control. Setting up the same id on postback allowed the CheckBox status to be updated with the user's choise.

```
void CreateTable()
        {
            dummyLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();            
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.Text = i.ToString();
                cb.AutoPostBack = true;
                cb.EnableViewState = true;
                cb.ID =  i.ToString();
                cell1.Controls.Add(cb);

                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                cell2.Text = String.Format("Clm : {0} - Row : {1}", 2, i);

                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                row.Cells.Add(cell2);

                usrTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```